# (ZEND) Route to index.phtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

I'm making a button that refreshes a specific div, the div is located in the index.phtml.

```
 $('#jumbotron-table').load(document.URL);
```

Is not working, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it would help if you specify exactly what "not working" means. Does anything happen on-screen?, is there an error message in the Javascript console?, if you enter the fuction in immediate mode into the debugger does it work then?, what if you use a fixed URL rather than a variable?

document.URL is the URL of the currently loaded page, so you're loading a copy of the current page into a div within that page. Sounds a bit odd but I can't say that it sounds impossible.

Try something like this-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <table id="myTable"><tr><td>Content</td></tr></table>
</html>

<script>
var contentURL= "Stackoverflow_01.html";

$().ready(function() {
  $('#myTable tr td').load(contentURL);
});

</script>
```

This loads the content of the target file into a table cell in the starting file.

Comment: What I meant was that, nothing happens when I push the button.

Comment: My lack of simple understanding of programming just showed there.. I obviously need to call in the table from a seperate file and then update it. I was trying to update a table inside the same file.